# Why do I keep getting the first ID asp.net(vb.net) for drop down?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have written a script like below, my table  record display something like in the picture.

[image]

```
Dim objDataTable As System.Data.DataTable = _objCommonData.fnLoadCompanyList(1)

ddlCompany.DataSource = objDataTable
ddlCompany.DataTextField = "company_name"
ddlCompany.DataValueField = "id"
ddlCompany.DataBind()
```

and I wrote something like this,

```
   If ddlCompany.SelectedValue = "" Then
       strCompany = "0"
   ElseIf ddlCompany.SelectedValue = "0" Then
       strCompany = "0"
   Else
       strCompany = ddlCompany.SelectedValue
   End If
```

What did I miss? It keeps returning `strCompany = 1`.

Comment: It could help you if you put a breakpoint on the first "IF", then see what value you get for "SelectedValue".

Comment: @vonv. i got "1", even though i selected "3"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may need to do:

```
If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then
    Dim objDataTable As System.Data.DataTable = _objCommonData.fnLoadCompanyList(1)

    ddlCompany.DataSource = objDataTable
    ddlCompany.DataTextField = "company_name"
    ddlCompany.DataValueField = "id"
    ddlCompany.DataBind()
End If
```

Sometimes this issue occurs because the list binds every time and wipes out the selection on rebind.

Comment: Hey it works! but is this going to cause me a problem in the future?

Comment: No the items bound from the database are stored in viewstate.  So as long as viewstate is turned on, this is no problem.  (Note: it can work without viewstate; just assuming you have it turned on).